# How to identify apple consumable purchase at server side (PHP)

Tags: php, ios, in-app-purchase, applepay, receipt-validation

I have simple API gate on my server, where I receive info about inApps from  iOS clients applications.

I validate the receipt from APNC and try to detect which product has been purchased. But I don't understand how to do this..

I receive something like this:

```
... -- common info about request 
[in_app] => Array
        [0] => Array
            (
                [quantity] => 1
                [product_id] => sp100
                [transaction_id] => 1000000175969407
                [original_transaction_id] => 1000000175969407
                [purchase_date] => 2015-10-15 14:08:31 Etc/GMT
                [purchase_date_ms] => 1444918111000
                [purchase_date_pst] => 2015-10-15 07:08:31 America/Los_Angeles
                [original_purchase_date] => 2015-10-15 14:08:31 Etc/GMT
                [original_purchase_date_ms] => 1444918111000
                [original_purchase_date_pst] => 2015-10-15 07:08:31 America/Los_Angeles
                [is_trial_period] => false
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [quantity] => 1
                [product_id] => sp100
                [transaction_id] => 1000000176387075
                [original_transaction_id] => 1000000176387075
                [purchase_date] => 2015-10-19 11:26:48 Etc/GMT
                [purchase_date_ms] => 1445254008000
                [purchase_date_pst] => 2015-10-19 04:26:48 America/Los_Angeles
                [original_purchase_date] => 2015-10-19 11:26:48 Etc/GMT
                [original_purchase_date_ms] => 1445254008000
                [original_purchase_date_pst] => 2015-10-19 04:26:48 America/Los_Angeles
                [is_trial_period] => false
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [quantity] => 1
                [product_id] => sp100
                [transaction_id] => 1000000177517396
                [original_transaction_id] => 1000000177517396
                [purchase_date] => 2015-10-27 12:46:44 Etc/GMT
                [purchase_date_ms] => 1445950004000
                [purchase_date_pst] => 2015-10-27 05:46:44 America/Los_Angeles
                [original_purchase_date] => 2015-10-27 12:46:44 Etc/GMT
                [original_purchase_date_ms] => 1445950004000
                [original_purchase_date_pst] => 2015-10-27 05:46:44 America/Los_Angeles
                [is_trial_period] => false
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [quantity] => 1
                [product_id] => sp200
                [transaction_id] => 1000000176387194
                [original_transaction_id] => 1000000176387194
                [purchase_date] => 2015-10-19 11:27:15 Etc/GMT
                [purchase_date_ms] => 1445254035000
                [purchase_date_pst] => 2015-10-19 04:27:15 America/Los_Angeles
                [original_purchase_date] => 2015-10-19 11:27:15 Etc/GMT
                [original_purchase_date_ms] => 1445254035000
                [original_purchase_date_pst] => 2015-10-19 04:27:15 America/Los_Angeles
                [is_trial_period] => false
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [quantity] => 1
                [product_id] => sp200
                [transaction_id] => 1000000176387495
                [original_transaction_id] => 1000000176387495
                [purchase_date] => 2015-10-19 11:30:18 Etc/GMT
                [purchase_date_ms] => 1445254218000
                [purchase_date_pst] => 2015-10-19 04:30:18 America/Los_Angeles
                [original_purchase_date] => 2015-10-19 11:30:18 Etc/GMT
                [original_purchase_date_ms] => 1445254218000
                [original_purchase_date_pst] => 2015-10-19 04:30:18 America/Los_Angeles
                [is_trial_period] => false
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [quantity] => 1
                [product_id] => sp200
                [transaction_id] => 1000000178496582
                [original_transaction_id] => 1000000178496582
                [purchase_date] => 2015-11-03 11:11:05 Etc/GMT
                [purchase_date_ms] => 1446549065000
                [purchase_date_pst] => 2015-11-03 03:11:05 America/Los_Angeles
                [original_purchase_date] => 2015-11-03 11:11:05 Etc/GMT
                [original_purchase_date_ms] => 1446549065000
                [original_purchase_date_pst] => 2015-11-03 03:11:05 America/Los_Angeles
                [is_trial_period] => false
            )

    )
```

And the question how to detect which product has been purchased by user ?

Comment: Are you looking for `product_id`, it looks like the user has purchased both `sp100` and `sp200` 3 times

Comment: At now, I loop through items, and look for new transaction_id